# Update listBox For Picture Viewer

Tags: c#

i made picture Viewer.
problem is when copy and paste several Pictures in Directory manually(from folder in Directory Folder) listbox should refresh and show new items in it.
i want when click on reFresh button, new items show in listBox
try it in button as reFresh, but nothing Happen. is anyOne can Help.
Thanks.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    string currentDir = "";

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var fb = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            if (fb.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                currentDir = fb.SelectedPath;

                textBoxDirectory.Text = currentDir;

                var dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(currentDir);

                var files = dirinfo.GetFiles().Where(c => c.Extension.Equals(".jpg") || c.Extension.Equals(".jpeg") || c.Extension.Equals(".bmp") || c.Extension.Equals(".png"));

                foreach (var image in files)
                {
                    listBoxImage.Items.Add(image.Name);
                }
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an Error: " + ex.Message + "" + ex.Source);
        }
    }

    private void listBoxImage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var selectedImage = listBoxImage.SelectedItems[0].ToString();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedImage) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentDir))
            {
                var fullPath = Path.Combine(currentDir, selectedImage);
                pictureBoxImagePreview.Image = Image.FromFile(fullPath);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }

    private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBoxImage.Refresh();
        listBoxImage.Update();
    }
```

[Picture Viewer Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbUVh.jpg)

Comment: [Refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.refresh?view=net-5.0) and [Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.update?view=net-5.0) don't re-read the folder and add the new files to the listbox.

Comment: @Steve thsnks. What do you suggest? how should see new Items in ListBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.refresh?view=net-5.0) and [Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.update?view=net-5.0) don't re-read the folder and add the new files to the listbox.
Instead I suggest to take the code that load the file list and create a private function. Then you can call that code from both the select folder button and from the refresh button.

```
private void LoadFiles()
{
    try
    {
        var dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(currentDir);
        var files = dirinfo.GetFiles().Where(c => c.Extension.Equals(".jpg") || c.Extension.Equals(".jpeg") || c.Extension.Equals(".bmp") || c.Extension.Equals(".png"));

        // This is required to not add the same file two times
        listBoxImage.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var image in files)
        {
            listBoxImage.Items.Add(image.Name);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There was an Error: " + ex.Message + "" + ex.Source);
    }

}


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fb = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    if (fb.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        currentDir = fb.SelectedPath;
        textBoxDirectory.Text = currentDir;
        LoadFiles();
    }
}

private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadFiles();
}
```